# Django: How to get id from different model

Tags: django

I hope my title is enough to answer my question, I just want to get the id of model (StudentProfile) when I click the report from the model (studentDiscount), my error is from this line in my admin.py
**obj.Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users.pk** I don't know if that is correct.
[image]

```
@admin.register(studentDiscount)
class studentDiscount(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('Students_Enrollment_Records', 'Discount_Type','my_url_field')
    ordering = ('Students_Enrollment_Records',)
    search_fields = ('Students_Enrollment_Records',)

    def my_url_field(self, obj):
        return format_html("<a href='https://www.ucc.ph/enrollmentform/?StudentID={}'>Report", obj.Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users.pk)
    my_url_field.allow_tags = False
    my_url_field.short_description = 'Report'
```

models.py

```
class StudentProfile(models.Model):
   Image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images',null=True,blank=True)
   Username = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
   Password = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
   lrn = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True)
   Firstname = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
   Middle_Initial = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
   Lastname = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)

class StudentsEnrollmentRecord(models.Model):
    Student_Users = models.ForeignKey(StudentProfile, related_name='students', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    School_Year = models.ForeignKey(SchoolYear, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Courses = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Section = models.ForeignKey(Section, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,blank=True)

class studentDiscount(models.Model):
    Students_Enrollment_Records = models.ForeignKey(StudentsEnrollmentRecord, related_name='+',
                                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Discount_Type = models.ForeignKey(Discount, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,blank=True)
```

Comment: obj.Students_Enrollment_Records.Student_Users.pk this will give ID from StudentProfile model if obj is instance of studentDiscount model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you really should check [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

To get the `id` you should use: `obj.Students_Enrollment_Records.Student_Users.id`

Comment: why all models should have the `id`?

Comment: @BearBrown No, you are right. But he/she asked for `id`. `pk` can email or something, so it depends on your needs.